# Something wrong in making <object> tag revisable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my webApp when a user clicks on an 'Open video' button, a `<div>` becomes visible which contains an `<object>` tag that displays an '.flv' file. It also has a close button which hides the `<div>` and removes `<object>` tag (which is added dynamically).

But when I again click on a that 'Open video' button, the controls of the player do not appear correctly, the video has some problems and I can hear only voices.

But when I clear the history, refresh the page and open it again, it works properly.

What is wrong here? Can anybody help me please.